# Programmatically Positioning Shapes -- Packing Efficiently

Tags: language-agnostic, constraints, constraint-programming

Let's say I have some abstract shapes defined each with a width and height (let's make them rectangles for the sake of simplicity). How can I place as many of them as possible on a single canvas (just a term, not necessarily HTML5 canvas) of a defined width and height?

Obviously this is some sort of constraint satisfaction problem, but I don't really know where to start (besides brute force). Googling just turns up unrelated results (probably because I don't know what to search for). What would be a good algorithm or what would be a good way to go about creating an algorithm to do this?

[Fizz](http://fizz.bloom.io/) is a good example. Shapes (circles, in this case) appear in groups and don't overlap each other and they stay out of each other's way. My use case is more of a one time positioning deal. Another example is [SpriteRight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVWn4NdX1wY&feature=player_embedded), which places as efficiently as possible within certain boundaries.

Comment: Google bin packing algorithm, you'll find what you need to make a start.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could profit from constraint logic programming over finite domains ([clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)).

Consider the question and answers to [Prolog constraint processing: Packing squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623775/prolog-constraint-processing-packing-squares). It shows several methods, one of which uses dedicated [placement constraints](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Placement-Constraints.html) to find a layout of non-overlapping rectangles in 2D.

clpfd also enables you to enforce *additional constraints* in addition to the packing constraint. There are both free (e.g., [SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) and [YAP](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/index.html)) and commercial (e.g., [SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/)) [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) implementations which support [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

Answer (score 0):

I found an [open source example](http://incise.org/2d-bin-packing-with-javascript-and-canvas.html) with JavaScript and HTML5 canvas. Rectangles are randomly generated and then packed. The author, however, makes no claims as to efficiency.

I also found [an article](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/) which looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at  http://www.aimms.com/downloads/application-examples/circle-packing. Here mathematical programming/modeling is used to solve the circle-packing problem. Other variants can also be defined. Special bin-packing constraints exist in Constraint Programming, http://www.aimms.com/cp.

In general, mathematical programming is a good way to approach such problems.