# Using SVG for visualization

Tags: xml, svg, prolog, data-visualization

When writing an answer to the recent question [Prolog Constraint Processing : Packing Squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623775/prolog-constraint-processing-packing-squares) I wanted to visualize the answers that Prolog + clpfd gave me.

To do that I wrote some dirty Prolog code for emitting suitable [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) commands by using Prolog builtin "predicates" `format/2` and `write/1`, like so:

```
drawBoxesWithIM_at_pix(Sizes,Positions,P) :-
    Colors = ["#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff","#ffff00","#ff00ff","#00ffff"],
    write(' -strokewidth 2 -stroke white'),
    nth1(N,Positions,Xb+Yb),
    nth1(N,Sizes,    Wb*Hb),
    nth1(N,Colors,   Color),
    format(' -draw "fill ~sb0 roundrectangle ~d,~d ~d,~d ~d,~d"',
           [Color, Xb*P+3,Yb*P+3, (Xb+Wb)*P-3,(Yb+Hb)*P-3, P/2,P/2]),
    false.
drawBoxesWithIM_at_pix(_,_,_).
```

The quick hack worked well, **however** I feel the code I wrote feels bloated and somewhat dirty... I would like to find a more declarative alternative for doing 2D visualizations like these. I feel like SVG could be a good choice.

Now, SVG is based on XML and several Prolog systems offer libraries for handling XML as a part of their standard libraries.

Are there Prolog libraries for SVG? Or other suitable 2D/(3D) data-visualization frameworks/tools with Prolog bindings?

What reasonable approaches do you see?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1, good visualisations for CLP(FD) tasks and search processes definitely warrant some attention. Make sure to check out Neumerkel et al., [*Visualizing Solutions with Viewers*](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/wlpe97.pdf) for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the work of [Helmut Simonis](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425231948/http://4c.ucc.ie:80/%7Ehsimonis/) et al, who have done extensive work in this area in the context of [Cosytec CHIP](https://www.cosytec.com/production_scheduling/chip/optimization_product_chip.htm) and the European [DiSCiPL](https://web.archive.org/web/20180618142422/https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/10722311_1) project.

A more recent open-source offshoot of this is the [CP-Viz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpviz/) system ([paper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpviz/), [slides](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810095506/http://www.4c.ucc.ie/%7Ehsimonis/cpviz-cp2010-slides.pdf)).  CP-Viz is distributed together with the free [ECLiPSe CLP](https://eclipseclp.org) system, and to my knowledge has also been ported to [SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se) and the Java-based [Choco](https://choco-solver.org/).  CP-Viz uses XML traces and can produce and display SVG output:

[image: CP-Viz Architecture]

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has a pack to interface to .dia, one for graphml files, and one for graphviz